# Getting client signal in freeradius

Tags: networking, radius

Hi I am new here and new to networking. I have installed latest freeradius and coovachilli in ubuntu 14.04. I want to know is it possible to get client signal in freeradius?

I found

```
iwlist scan
```

but it returns

```
"Interface doesn't support scanning"
```

I want this kind of information, at least I want to get the signal level.

[information i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npAvC.png)

I use **eth0** as the source of internet and connected from available router to my pc acted as server and **eth1** to share the connection connected from my pc to switch. I have another router connect to the switch and it's working fine with the freeradius and coovachilli.

I just don't know how to get the signal. Is it possible? Is there a way?